# How can I add Smarty function in append function of Jquery?

Tags: jquery, smarty

I need to include some code with [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function of `Jquery` but I also need to insert an `if` of `Smarty` inside of it. I am totally stuck here.

Here is the code I have right now:

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
        <th> Header </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id = "body">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$("#body").append("<tr>" +
                  "<td>{if $data.number eq 3}<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>{/if}</td>" +
                  "</tr>");
```

but it detects the `if` of `Smarty` as text and no as an Smarty function. I am sure I am going in the wrong way but I cannot find any other solution.

I also tried using `{literal}{/literal}` before the `{if}` statement but the behaviour it is the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Smarty runs on the server, jQuery runs on the client. So, no, that's not how it works.

Comment: @Tomalak And how can I get more or less a behaviour similar to this? Or is it impossible?

Comment: It is. There are many HTML templating engines available. I would choose one that has implementations for client-side (i.e. JS) and server-side (i.e. PHP), this way you don't need to switch template dialects and maybe even can re-use templates. [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) comes to mind, or its cousin [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). For both of them JS and PHP versions are available, with a little work you can get rid of Smarty.

Comment: @Tomalak is there really a point to implement whole templating engine just for one if statement?

Comment: That being said, you can achieve the same *effect* (dynamically generated HTML) by using jQuery and custom JS logic, but I would recommend separating keeping logic and presentation by using a templating engine if you do more than just the most basic HTML generation.

Comment: @entio No, but I take it that since the OP seems to be using a server-side templating engine there is likely a bit more templating going on than the one-liner sample shows.

Comment: @Tomalak fair point. I found myself in doubts, as i don't know where does the data come from. It can as well be user (or frontend) generated. Otherwise why wouldn't OP do the check on serverside?

Comment: The central point really is: Where do you want to do your HTML generation? If you want to it in PHP, fine. If you want to do it on the client, fine. Try not to do *both* unless you have a *really* good reason. Get your strategy straight before you try to figure out detail questions like this one.

Comment: Is that jquery script in a .js file or in the template file?

Answer (score 0):

Smarty runs on the server, jQuery runs on the client, so You cannot run smarty function on client. You can, however, do it this way

```
// at first append empty row with data-number ($data-number should be echoed in php)
var currentRow = $('<tr data-number="$data.number"><tr />').appendTo('#body');

// then append Your link if condition is met
if(currentRow.attr('data-number') == 3) {
    currentRow.append('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>')
}
```

It requires You, however, to have data available on clientSide. Is that the case?

Comment: The data of `$data.number` comes from PHP so I do not think so :S

Comment: Then why won't You do the check on backend?